# Looping through arrays in Python3

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose I have a list of five different colours, `colour = ['red', 'blue', ...]` etc. I then want to create a loop for making an arbitrary amount of circles defined by the tkinter modules. That would mean something like

```
def Circles():
    y = 0
    x = 0
    while y <= 900 and x <= 900:
        x = x + 100
        y = y + 100
        w.create_oval(x, y, 0, 0, fill='red')
```

How would I include a loop for that `fill='red'` part, where I instead want `fill=colour[N]`, where `N` would change in a loop? So the first circle would be red, next blue, next green etc? I also know that these ones overlap and I will try to make them not overlap, but that's not the question here.

Comment: Since `x` and `y` are the same, use 1 variable and use a `for` loop: `for x in range(0,1000,100):`

Comment: Also as an aside, you have a *list* of colors, definitely not an *array*.

Comment: Hello Edwin and welcome to the site.  We like to keep questions to the point here, so I trimmed yours down a bit.  Feel free to edit again if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).
Also as you increment both x and y by 100, up to 900, use range.

```
from itertools import cycle
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange']

def Circles():
    cycling_colors = cycle(colors)
    for i in range(0, 901, 100):
        w.create_oval(i, i, 0, 0, fill=next(cycling_colors))
```

Comment: It's better to use `next(cycling_colors)`... (changes between 2.x and 3.x semantics) - `next(...)` will work on both

Comment: I'd probably also be tempted to do `for i, c in zip(range(0, 901, 100), cycle(colors)): w.create_oval(i, i, 0, 0, fill=c)` but given we don't know if it's 2.x or 3.x, on 2.x you'd definitely need `izip` or else you'd never exit the loop :)

Comment: Thank you! I will try to make sense of the syntax of itertools!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way, if you want to make nested loop:

```
colours = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

def Circles():
    y = 0
    x = 0
    while y <= 900 and x <= 900:
        x = x + 100
        y = y + 100
        for color in colours:
            w.create_oval(x, y, 0, 0, fill=colour)

Circles()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Circles():
    y = 0
    x = 0
    while y <= 900 and x <= 900:
        x = x + 100
        y = y + 100
        #iterate the colour list
        for colo in colour:
            w.create_oval(x, y, 0, 0, fill=colo)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you may want to iterate over the plane of x an y. 
As for color, agreed, cycle is the right approach for the colors.

```
from itertools import cycle
def gen():
   color_cyclist = cycle('red', 'blue', 'green')
   for x in range(0,1000, 100):
       for y in range(0, 1000, 100):
           yield x, y, next(color_cyclist)

for x, y, color in gen():
    w.create(x, y, 0, 0, fill=color)
```

Comment: I tried that for x and for y loop on my own, before I came here. Python crashed when I tried it! Yours works just fine. Seems I need time :)